# Android adding css file

Tags: android, css, android-widget, android-styles

I want to add a css file in my Android application to change the look and feel.

How can I add and implement CSS in an Android application?

Comment: Please mark one of these awesome answers as best answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing an android native application, you need to set your styles through xml file. Android does not support css files. and if you are developing an android web application you can css styles as in normal web application.

Following is the example of how to set styles to a TextView.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" 
    android:textSize="16sp" android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold" android:background="@drawable/border_cell">
</TextView>
```

We have various attributes through which we can apply styles.

For further reference please refer to the following link.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add CSS/html file in android. Copy the CSS or Html file in asserts folder then use it as weblink.

```
 link.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/test.html");
```